# How to evaluate clusters' quality using a distance matrix in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to customize a hierarchical cluster procedure using a correlation distance between variables, and I need to evaluate the cluster quality. But, all the methods of cluster quality evaluation I found in python are observation-oriented and don't use distance matrix as input.

For example, the cluster evaluation scores available in sci-kit learn, SciPy or clusteval do not provide a how-to-use the distance matrix as input to compute any of the following quality metrics that are based on distances:

1. Davies–Bouldin index
2. calinski_harabasz
3. Silhouette

Do you have any solution for accessing cluster quality using custom distance metrics in hierarchical clustering?

## Distance-Matrix-based Hierarchical Clustering

```
DistanceMatrix = 1-abs(pipe6.Stats())
N = DistanceMatrix.shape[0]
score = []
for K in range(2, N-1):
    hclus = skclus.FeatureAgglomeration(n_clusters=K,
                                        linkage="complete",
                                        metric="precomputed")
    hclus.fit(DistanceMatrix)
    clusters = hclus.labels_
    Quality = metrics.davies_bouldin_score(X=DistanceMatrix,
                                           labels=clusters)
    score.append(Quality)
```

Answer (score 0):

With Silhouette you can use `metric=precomputed` and pass a distance matrix.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use the `FeatureAgglomeration` class from the `sklearn.cluster` module, with which can perform hierarchical clustering on a precomputed distance matrix. You can then use the `davies_bouldin_score` function from the `sklearn.metrics` module, which can accept a distance matrix as input, to evaluate the cluster quality.

Here is an example of code that implements this approach:

```
import sklearn.cluster as skclus
import sklearn.metrics as metrics

DistanceMatrix = 1 - abs(pipe6.Stats()) # correlation distance
N = DistanceMatrix.shape[0]
score = []
for K in range(2, N - 1):
    hclus = skclus.FeatureAgglomeration(n_clusters=K, linkage="complete", metric="precomputed")
    hclus.fit(DistanceMatrix)
    clusters = hclus.labels_
    Quality = metrics.davies_bouldin_score(X=DistanceMatrix, labels=clusters)
    score.append(Quality)
```

Another possible solution is to use the `linkage` function from the `scipy.cluster.hierarchy` module, which can also perform hierarchical clustering on a precomputed distance matrix. However, you need to convert your redundant square matrix into a condensed vector form, which contains only the upper triangular elements of the matrix. You can use the `squareform` function from the `scipy.spatial.distance` module to do this conversion. Then you can use any cluster quality metric that accepts a vector array of observations as input, such as `silhouette_score` or `calinski_harabasz_score` from the `sklearn.metrics module`.

Here is an example of code that implements this approach:

```
import scipy.spatial.distance as ssd
import scipy.cluster.hierarchy as sch
import sklearn.metrics as metrics

DistanceMatrix = 1 - abs(pipe6.Stats()) # correlation distance
distArray = ssd.squareform(DistanceMatrix) # condensed distance matrix
Z = sch.linkage(distArray, method="complete", metric="euclidean") # linkage matrix
max_d = 25 # distance threshold for cluster formation
clusters = sch.fcluster(Z, max_d, criterion="distance") # cluster labels
Quality1 = metrics.silhouette_score(X=distArray, labels=clusters) # silhouette score
Quality2 = metrics.calinski_harabasz_score(X=distArray, labels=clusters) # calinski-harabasz score
```